# setInterval timer works too fast in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, setinterval

I've just starting coding this year for class, anyways this is the simple timer I have been using to change pictures on my website and it works fine.
I made a jQuery Mobile site for class by adapting my HTML etc so everything is the same including this bit of code, however when I view my site on my phone the timer is going way too fast like about every half a second instead of every 3 seconds.

This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function workshop(){
    var pic = new Array('1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg');
    var image = 0;
    var changePic = setInterval(function() {Timer()}, 3000);
function Timer(){
    image=Math.floor(Math.random()*pic.length);
    document.getElementById('id').src=pic[image];
}
}
</script>
```

I looked at using setTimeout instead of setInterval but it didn't want to work in my browser so I ended up here :3 Any ideas? Ty in advance

Answer (score 1):

So for anyone thats been having similar problems, finally got this figured out. The problem was that everytime the page was reloaded a new interval was started without finishing the old one, giving the illusion that it the timer was speeding up. Got some help from the teacher and we figured it out.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var changePic = 0;
function workshop(){
    changePic = clearInterval(changePic);
    var pic = new Array('1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg');
    var image = 0;
    changePic = setInterval(function() {Timer()}, 3000);
function Timer(){
    image=Math.floor(Math.random()*pic.length);
    document.getElementById('id').src=pic[image];
}
```

}

Just had to declare changePic globally in order to clear it before starting the new interval. Hope this helps anyone that had the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Problem you facing in mobile browser is: Your next cycle runs so quickly before your last cycle ends. Because every cycle do some calculations and then change the source of the image. Mobile/Mobile browsers  speed is very slow as compared to desktops so until it loads the image new cycle starts.

You have couple of solutions here:

- Increase the time
- Or, have small/optimized images when displaying on the mobile devices.